# Resolving SAS MACRO parameters

Tags: macros, sas

I am looking for a way to resolve the parameters of an already defined SAS MACRO. I know where to locate session defined macros (WORK.SASMACR/WORK.SASMAC1), but now I want to know go a step further and determine its parameters. So for example:

```
%macro test(val1, val2);
   %put &val1 &val2;
%mend test;


/* With proc catalog I can find the defined macro... */
proc catalog cat=work.SASMAC1;
   contents out=macros;
run;

/* How to create function/macro which takes the macro name and returns its arguments, eg:*/
%resolveMacroParams(test);
/* ...returns: */
val1 val2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,
Herman

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if the macro was compiled with the SOURCE option.  The following gives you a dataset with the macro text from which you could trivially obtain the arguments:

```
libname dummy 'c:\temp\';
options mstored sasmstore=dummy;
%macro test(val1, val2)/store source;
   %put &val1 &val2;
%mend test;
filename mymacr temp;
%copy TEST/lib=dummy source out=mymacr;

data test;
infile mymacr truncover;
input @1 line $100.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like values supplied as parameters to a function at its last call?

The definition of macro doesn't store it's values. Macro params are in local scope of that macro and their values are not anywhere AFTER the macro ends.

During execution you can find it in dictionary.macros:

So to keep it you'd have to change your macro like this:

```
%macro test(val1, val2);
proc sql;
create table TEST_VALS as 
select * from dictionary.macros
where scope='TEST'
;
quit;
%mend test;

%test(11, 22);
```

or put those values into some global macro variables.